# Accessing XML nonexistent attribute in ActionScript 2

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm not an AS developer and I just can't test this thing, but I'm curious about what happens when trying to access an nonexistent XML node attribute in ActionScript.
Given the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
    <file attr="val"></file>
</root>
```

What happen when trying to run this (pseudo)code:

```
var xml = new XML();
xml.ignoreWhite = true;
xml.onLoad = function (success){
    if (success){
        // marked line:
        var somevar = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.inexistentattr;*
    }
}
xml.load(file);
```

Does the "marked line" raise an error or something, or it just return an empty string or undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have supplied has no visible output and will not throw an error. `somevar` is assigned the value `undefined`, which you can see by tracing it out.

```
var xml = new XML();
xml.ignoreWhite = true;
xml.onLoad = function (success){
    if (success){
        var somevar = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.nonexistentattr;
        trace(somevar);  // undefined
    }
}
xml.load('test.xml');
```

Comment: As I have said I can't test it, but I mark it as the correct answer as it answers to my question :)